# How to design the layout for a web page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a front-end with HTML and CSS, I am unable to use the div and style them with CSS to have a look like below format.

[image: Sample Image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.students-page-container{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:space-between;
}
.label-style{
font-weight:600;
font-family:'sans-serif';
font-size:24px;
align-items: center;
color: black;
margin-left:2rem;
line-height:28.8px;
display:flex;
}
.button-style{
border:none;
background:none;
padding:none;
font-weight:400;
size:12px;
line-height:14.4px;
}
.box-design{
width: 100 %;
background-color: gray;
}
.child-one{
width: 50%
min-height"400px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
}
.child-two{
width: 25%
min-height"200px;
background-color:white;
float:right;
}
.child-three{
width: 25%
min-height"200px;
background-color:white;
float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Top Row Container-->
<div class="students-page-container">
<div class="label-style">
<span> student number: &nbsp; 92837293</span>
</div>
<div>
<button class="button-style">
<u> all students</u>
</button>
</div>
</div>
<!-- for the boxes -->
<div class="box-design">
<div class="child-one">
<p> Studnt Name: &nbsp; mike jordan</p>
....
...
...
..
<hr>
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="child-two">
<p> Alerts</p>
</div>
<div class="child-three">
<p> Contact Details</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to display  first row student number with a link to all students in the correct format. But as soon as i am trying to write other div elements for boxes and setting min-height. the box is overriding the exiting top and header of the page.

I am quite new to front-end and learning .any help would be greatly appreciated

Expecting how to achieve the Layout which is high-lighted with red box
[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: You are better off not asking and keep struggling through it.